# Customize the property field of Blend designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, designer, blend

I'm authoring some controls for my WPF application and i wish to customize the property fields of Blend as others controls that already exists in the framework.

For example, the [`DataStateBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723952(v=expression.40).aspx) control, it's have an `object` property that’s suggest the use of binding, and also, have two more `string` properties that suggest the selection of visual state names.

[image: Sample of what i'm saying]

The DataStateBehavior is just an example, many others WPF controls uses different ways to set the properties, like colors properties that have a special tool to adjust the desired color. I know that some property "types" automatically rules the VisualStudio or Blend designer way to show/edit then, like as mentioned color property, but this object and string properties that are in my example image appears not being applied with this magic.

I'm already tried the annotation attributes described in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8(v=vs.120).aspx), but with no success.

How can i suggest a binding, or the selection of a view state name like showed in the image?

Comment: That link is for _WinForms_.  Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938(v=vs.90).aspx which is for WPF Extensibility

Comment: Is it possible that blend is simply getting the list of Dependency Properties from the control, and displaying those?

Comment: @MickyD The documentation in that link is quite deep, but I think that is about how to create your own tooling for the WPF designer, not for use the existent ones.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes, but i made a test creating a new control with exacly the same properties of the `DataStateBehavior` control, and i did't get the same result.

Comment: @HélioTibagí It's no more _"deep"_ than your link for your WinForms link and if you understand how custom editors in WinForms works then you are well on your way to WPF.  I doubt you can _override_ the editor to use for a particular property if say a `Color` property already is suggesting to use say a "color" editor.  And why would you want to on a global scale?